# How to get width of a field of a struct in SystemVerilog without create dummy variable?

Tags: system-verilog

How to get the width of a field in a struct? I tried to use

```
$bits(struct_type_name.field_name)
```

but it can't compile. I have to create a dummy variable and apply `$bits()` on it. But that will create a lot garbage if I need a lot of width.

Is there any better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately a field_name of a struct type is not another type or a variable. Two suggestions

1. Use a `typedef` when declaring the _field_name_ and use `$bits(field_name_t)`
2. Declare an automatic variable local to the scope where you need the $bits. It will probably get optimized away, but not before the type information gets extracted for $bits.